# Android HttpPost Login action

Tags: android, authentication, http-post

Actually I'm doing tests if my application can Login from android phone via http post.I'm sending a few extra parameters which I need for testing the application,but everytime I run it I can login even my params are true. Here is the code that I'm using.

```
package com.android.login.test;

/* new_auth_data=1&     - If there is new user ot password changes
 * debug_data=1&        - Debugging data sent from terminal
 * client_api_ver=1.5.1.422&    - API version of clients terminal
 * timestamp=1314195661&        - THE timestamp of first sync of new device 
 * password_hash=d2824b50d07cfed3d82a480d5d87437af11a4f7e&      - A valid password hash
 * set_locale=en_US&        - 
 * device_os_type=iPhone%20Simulator%204.3.2&       - The device OS code - for mobiles
 * username_hash=6d229fe6593f5250653e3b29184a6e370fc7ffe5&      - A valid username hash
 * device_sync_type=3&      - 3 is for iphone, 4 will be for android
 * device_identification_string=iPhone%20Simulator%204.3.2&     - Device identificator (friendly name)
 * device_resolution=320x480&       - No need of explanation
 * device_identificator=255634997       - This identificator is catched with getDeviceId() function

*/
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

        EditText username,password;
Button login;
TextView error;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
    final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
    final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.rpc.example.com"); 


    postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username_hash", username.getText().toString()));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_hash", password.getText().toString()));
    /*postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("debug_data","1"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_api_ver","1.5.1.422"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timestamp","1314195661"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("set_locale","en_US"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_os_type","Android 2.2"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_sync_type","3"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_identificator","255634997"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_identification_string",deviceId));*/
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Log.d("myapp", "response " + response.getEntity());

                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                error.setText(responseBody);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                username.setText(e.toString());
            }

        }
    });

}

}
```

I'm setting all the params in code because as I said it's just for test.As a result after the executing http post I need to send to the server something like that :

```
new_auth_data=1&debug_data=1&client_api_ver=1.5.1.422&timestamp=1314195661&password_hash=d2824b50d07cfed3d82a480d5d87437af11a4f7e&set_locale=en_US&device_os_type=iPhone%20Simulator%204.3.2&username_hash=6d229fe6593f5250653e3b29184a6e370fc7ffe5&device_sync_type=3&device_identification_string=iPhone%20Simulator%204.3.2&device_resolution=320x480&device_identificator=255634997
```

How can I fix this so I can test a login?any ideas or suggestions are welcomed!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what is happening now... are you saying that it always says "Correct Username or Password" even if it is incorrect? Can you tell us what the server is receiving?

Comment: It's always saying that the username and password are not correct.And how can I see what the server is receiving...from my app or from server (sorry but that's my first synchronization with server and user login process).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether you can login to your server using desktop browser or some utility like curl command line utility? Username and password hash mentioned in your comment and in code are different. You should be able to see parameters received on server with the help of server logs.

Comment: Actually I checked and I can login to the server with the hashed username and password from browser.I'm just trying to post them directly as a string,not to generate them and see if I can login that way.About the different hashes...I know,they are from test in iphone simulator,so they were just for an example to show what I should post to the server.And after I post the params to the server I get a data packet which send me if I'm logged in or the error.

Comment: Well, in that case you will have to check the content received on server side when you login using above code. "UrlEncodedFormEntity" class uses "US-ASCII" encoding as default encoding which causes issues sometimes. Try setting encoding as UTF-8. It's hard to determine the cause without knowing what is going on server side.

Comment: Actually with the changed code it's working fine..I cannot log in,but at least I'm getting a responce from server and it's sending me a data packet,which now I have to find how to get the data from it.So now the question is more different.Thanks for help anyway!I really appreciate it : )

Answer (score 0):

To get the response you should do like this:

```
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        String html = null;
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            try {
                html = streamToString(instream);
            } finally {
                instream.close();
            }
        }
```

If you have any further questions don't hesitate to ask me.