# Android autofill web login username and password

Tags: android, autologin

Does anyone know how I would go about autofilling the username and password of a website on the browser in Android given that I have the login URL, the username and the password? Is there a simple way to do this or is somthing more complicated required? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript :

```
String username = "cristian";
webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('username').value = '"+username+"';");
```

So basically, what you have to do is a big string of JavaScript code that will get those fields and put values on them; also, you can enable/disable the submit button from JavaScript.

Source : [Fill fields in webview automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961568/fill-fields-in-webview-automatically)

Comment: That's good to know but I was hoping for a generic solution which can be used for all websites where the ids of the password and username input fields vary. Any ideas?