# Passing data from java class to Web View html

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I'm loading below html in my `webView`

https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/?ui=2&ik=25c0c425c6&view=att&th=138db54ff27ad34b&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_h5ahtmbe0&safe=1&zw&saduie=AG9B_P9YNooGjsk_jLefLptQ9q15&sadet=1343790299575&sads=-yBVsLKP_2mh7zMfYLCF7sL1u-w

Now what I want to do is to fill the textbox in the `html` that came from my java class variable and then automatically hit submit.

But I don't have any idea how to do this.

Any thougths will be appreciated.

Comment: WARNING: To those thinking `loadUrl` is the way to go, check out the answer with `evaluateJavascript` in it. It's easy to overlook.

Answer (score 58):

First, your URL seems not available.

If you want to do data exchange between android app and your web app/web page you can achieve this via javascript.

Here is an example from Android official site:

Create a class like this:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

In your `WebView`:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

In your web page:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

If you wanna pass something to your webpage, just calling corresponding javascript function:

```
String str = "xxx";
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:xxx('"+str+"')");
```

Here is the Reference:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: what do you mean by this  myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:xxx('xxx')"); I'm also using load url to load my html so it is ok to use load url for a multiple times?

Comment: yes as long as the javascript function exists in your web page

Comment: I see that's why I will load the javascript because it has the code to pass some data.

Comment: please try and see if there is any problem;)

Comment: I' using this like what you said  web.loadUrl("javascript:holder(Test!)"); But I don't know how to get the value and assign it in html textbox

Comment: just write the javascript function to set the value you passed to html

Comment: just like this codes? document.getElementById("d").innerHTML="String"

Comment: Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available to your JavaScript (the method must also be public). If you do not provide the annotation, the method is not accessible by your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher.

Comment: @Happydev Thanks I'll update the answer accordingly ;)

Comment: Can the Java method I call from the JavaScript return a value, and can I use that value in the JavaScript?

Comment: How to listen **xxx** function in `component` instead `index.html`

Answer (score 30):

I would add that the load of the javascript function should be done when the html is loaded. To control that, you can use the following:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){   
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:init('" + theArgumentYouWantToPass + "')");
    }           
});
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
hola
adios
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function init(val){
// Do whatever you want with your parameter val
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Taken from [Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at null:1 Android exception in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633930/uncaught-referenceerror-myfunction-is-not-defined-at-null1-android-exception-i)

Comment: very very nice .... onPageFinished is important point that i forgot to use that...

Comment: Where can I add the android_asset folder

Comment: Wow `webview.loadUrl("javascript:init('" + theArgumentYouWantToPass + "')");` works great.

Comment: how to pass more than one value in it 
`webview.loadUrl("javascript:init('" + theArgumentYouWantToPass + "')");`

Comment: @AkshayNandwana    
`webView.loadUrl("javascript:init('" + selectedItemName+","+price + "')");`

in js
`function init(values) { var valuesArray=values.split(','); payment.items = valuesArray[0]; payment.amount = valuesArray[1];`

Answer (score 6):

Just enable DOM Storage and write `var x=` to string:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

webview.loadUrl(urlString);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    String js = "javascript:var x =document.getElementById('username').value = '"+user+"';var y=document.getElementById('password').value='"+pass+"';";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        view.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        view.loadUrl(js);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. I was trying to pass a 5MB JSON string to the WebView, and `loadUrl` wasn't capable of doing so. `evaluateJavascript`, on the other hand, had no issues with this.

Answer (score 4):

**Be careful** to call javascript function like this, the `str` may include single quote or other special characters.

```
String str = "xxx";
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:xxx('"+str+"')");
```

I suggest to encode the `str` in base64, and decode it on javascript side.

- Android

  ```
  String str = "xxx";
  //encode in base64
  String base64Str = Base64.encodeToString(str.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
  myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:xxx('"+ base64Str +"')");
  ```
- Javascript

  ```
  function xxx(val) {
      //decode from base64
      var str = atob(data)
  }
  ```

Comment: I think encoding data as `JSON` rather than `base64` would be more effective (at least in terms of 6 bytes per char vs 8 bytes per char). Any `JSON` value is a valid javascript value, so that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the paramter directly in the url

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/animation.html?message=testing");
```

Get the paramter in `html` file

```
var url_string = window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var message= url.searchParams.get("message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions by Hungr would work, but using the same [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) they point out, I do the following:

in my Android code WebAppInterface class:

```
@JavascriptInterface
fun provideData(val input: String): String{
val output = ""
//some operation with input
    return output
}
```

then in host activity for webview:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this), "Provider")
```

Inside your JS or HTML:

```
document.getElementbyId("Text").innerhtml = Provider.provideData(input);
```