# Return string from an android method to the html file, from webview

Tags: android

I have seen this article:-
[Passing data from java class to Web View html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752052/passing-data-from-java-class-to-web-view-html)

Can we return string from an android function to the html file in the webview of the android application.

Comment: Your subject and content are exactly the same, can you please clarify what you expect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement some Java class returning such string:

```
public class Bar {
  public String foo() {
    return "bla-bla-bla";
  }
}
```

After that you pass it to addJavascriptInterface method:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Bar(), "bar");
```

Now you have JavaScript object "bar":

```
alert(bar.foo());
```

Comment: thanks. I would have given u thumbs up but i dont have 15 reputation.