# How to insert date in webview from popup widow in android?

Tags: android, webview, android-popupwindow

right now i am working in pop-up window, i have successfully created a pop-up window over webview. Pop-up window will show buttons like Date and Name, once i click on the date button on the pop-up, it should show the current date with month and year on webview and one more thing it should also be movable on webview. Can anyone suggest any link or your ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, instead of putting minus to my question, you can send the link or paste if it has answer already that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the better way would be to create this dialog with javascript?

Anyway see these links:

- http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2012/03/16/android-development-javascript-bridge-example-fully-explained/
- http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html
- [Passing data from java class to Web View html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752052/passing-data-from-java-class-to-web-view-html)