# Call MainActivity method from another class in android

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I'm working on an android app. I want to pass some value from my `webview` to my android application.

I solved this problem successfully by using the solution given in [Passing data from java class to Web View html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752052/passing-data-from-java-class-to-web-view-html).

The problem that I'm facing is when I'm trying to call `MainActivity` methods from `JavaScriptInterface.java`, the methods are not being called or no errors are given.

here's what I have tried so far:

```
MainActivity act=new MainActivity();
act.myMethod() //This method is available in my activity
```

but it is not being called.

and

```
((MainActivity)getActivity).myMethod();

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void myMethod() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside MainActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

//JavaScriptInterface class

    class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onButtonClick(String toast1, String toast2) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast1+" | "+toast2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //THIS IS WORKING
        MainActivity act=new MainActivity();
        act.myMethod(); //NOT WORKING
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the `myMethod` will get called, but since you create the MainActivity yourself, it's not attached to anything.

In general, you shouldn't create a new MainActivity instance this way. To open a new MainActivity, you use an Intent.

In your case, you should have a reference to the original MainActivity instance, and call this method there. Not create a new one in any way, as you already have it running.

An easy way to solve it:

```
MainActivity.this.myMethod("Hello there")
```

You don't have to store `mContext` . You already are inside of MainActivity.

So, the full code would be:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");
}

public void myMethod(String test){
    Toast.makeText(this, test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public class WebAppInterface {

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        MainActivity.this.myMethod("Hello there");
    }
}

}
```

In fact, I think you can even avoid having the `MainActivity.this.` , and call `myMethod` directly.

Comment: My JavaScriptInterface class is on the MainActivity.java file. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank You for the comments! This soution works perfectly form me!

Comment: @Anirban To mark an answer as the correct one, press the V. To tell that it has helped a lot, you can press the up-arrow above the number.

Comment: Yup, of course I did that. But I don't have have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: @Anirban Oh ok.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating another object of MainActivity this is why its not getting displayed. You are passing the activity context to the interface so you can just

```
((MainActivity)mContext).myMethod();
```

Sample MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
}

public void myMethod(String test){
    Toast.makeText(this, test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        ((MainActivity)mContext).myMethod("hello");
    }
}

}
```

[Check out android documentation for more info](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#java)

Comment: Since it's not a static class, but in fact a part of MainActivity, it's not needed to store `mContext`, as you can reach the MainActivity instance directly.