# Passing data to local html file in android webView

Tags: android, html, kotlin, webview

I have some difficulties when trying to pass data to my html file. My html file is located at project root inside assets folder. In short, i am displaying my html file inside a webView.

This is portion of my mainActivity.kt, which is used to populate my webView

```
mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
val webSettings = mWebView.settings
webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/googlechart.html");
```

and here is portion of my googlechart.html, which is stored locally inside assets folder

```
var dataRow = [["mushroom", 1], ["fish", 3]]
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
data.addRows(dataRow);
```

I want to pass data from mainActivity.kt to my googlechart.html, per answer at [Passing data from java class to Web View html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752052/passing-data-from-java-class-to-web-view-html), it didn't explain how to pass data to a html file which is stored inside project root. How can i achieve that ?

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: @blackapps it is in my project folder, my bad

Comment: @blackapps it's been removed. hope it make the question a bit more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Simple solution

1. use Query when `loadUrl()`
2. get `document.location.href` in `script`
3. deal with your data

   - decode string, split, etc

#### example

If data is json

android

```kotlin
val json = JsonObject().apply {
    addProperty("age","28")
    addProperty("name","john")
    addProperty("contents","test")
}
val url = "file:///android_asset/test.html?$json"
binding.webView.loadUrl(url)
```

local `.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <H1>test</H1>
    <oi id="list">
    </oi>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function makeList() {
            const getOiTag = document.getElementById("list");

            const decodeUrl = decodeURI(document.location.href);
            const jsonStr = decodeUrl.split("?")[1];
            const json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

            for(i in json){
                const li = document.createElement("li")
                li.textContent = i + " : " + json[i];
                getOiTag.appendChild(li);
            }
        }
        makeList()

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer, the query used is nice to send a single string data but what if i want to pass a bit complex data, like array or object ?

Comment: If I were you, I'll just put any data in query and deal with(decode,...) in `script`. I tested `array` and `object`, It will show well. But just plain `string` is best for this case I think.

Comment: could you elaborate it in answer ? it would be very helpful

Comment: thank you, but i am still wondering why `val url = "file:///android_asset/test.html?$json"` always return me ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when displayed at webView, did yours works fine ?

Comment: Is your `.html` file name `test.html`?? not `googlechart .html`?  and check your `json` is can be shown in logcat. and I tested `json` work well as shown in screenshot. I used `JsonObject()` from `Gson`