# From android Webview with javascript, can I save a text as a file in assets folder in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, assets

My android app opens a Webview and run html and JavaScript from the server.
The JavaScript creates a data and I want to save the data as a file in the assets folder of my app.
Is this possible? and How?

Comment: Your android app can communicate with the webview. Which means you can call a function that is [injected into the webview's page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) and pass your text, then grab the passed text in your android app and save it.

Comment: Duplicate: [Passing data from java class to Web View html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752052/passing-data-from-java-class-to-web-view-html)

Comment: Hi Chris, as you said, addJavascriptInterface seems to be the right way. Thanks a lot for your help.