# how to automatically login the website in webview?

Tags: java, android

In my app I am having webview to load web pages Now I want to automatically login to the website loaded in the webview eg:Facebook.Help me to solve this.I am using Android Studio to develop app.
This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText url;
Button go;
WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv);
    url=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.urlEdit);
    go=(Button)findViewById(R.id.goBut);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            theWebsite=url.getText().toString();
            webView.loadUrl(theWebsite);
        }
    });
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: you need to develop web service  at server side and from webservice you can redirect directly login page in webview

Comment: Bro I want to enter username and password programmatically in webview page

Comment: So do you want to populate username and password and submit it automatically (without any user intervention)?

Comment: Yes Bro thats it

Comment: Hey @DineshS did you find out the solution to this? Even I am trying to login to a website but not happening.

Answer (score 2):

step 1) first of all enable javascript in your webview

step 2) on onPageFinished using javascript autofill username and password field and generate click on login button

```
wv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('Username').value = 'abc'");
wv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('Pass').value = 'xyz'");
wv.loadUrl("javascript:document.forms['Login'].submit()");
```

Comment: Thanks bro for your answer

Comment: This did not work for me. It showed a blank while screen with my username. my username should actually be seen in the username field

Comment: Try to use document.getElementById

Comment: @DineshS ,  even after using `document.getElementById` , i am facing same issue just like @abhishekmaharajpet

Comment: in javascript:document.forms['Login'].submit()")  what is 'Login' for Abhinay Sharma

Answer (score 0):

This explanation helped me.
[Fill form in WebView with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187908/fill-form-in-webview-with-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
view.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                }
```

instead of

```
view.loadUrl(js);
```

which is the answer I found everywhere else.