# pulling data from a website in android application

Tags: android

I want to ask, I have a website(HTML and javascript) that allows user to login, maintain thier account. Now I want to create an android application that allows user to login and then pulls thier account details from the website and display on the android app. I have no idea where to start? After user logged in how to pull that user's account details from website? Any suggestion where to start and what to look for???

Can I simply load the url of website for login? Would the website work fine on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to create a webservice to return a JSON or XML string with the information you need.

```
www.example.com/userDetails.php?userID=23&encryptedPassword=ACD23423FFFF23
```

If you need more security you can create a mechanism that generates expirable hashes that can be used for a specified period of time.

```
www.example.com/userDetails.php?userID=23&expirableHash=FFFF234234234DDCCCEEEE22
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! This sounds good, Now I will have to look how to create webservice to return a JSON or XML string, can you suggest me any tutorial or resource for that? Will be really great full!

Comment: or is it a good practise if I simply load URL of website for login as WebView? Would the website work fine on android?

Comment: it will show fine in the webview, if your website is optimized for mobile. As for the webservice approach you can begin with that. http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json . Please mark the reply as answer if it answers your question. Thanks

Comment: Hey, If I use WebView, Can I store user's credentials's on the android application so that user does not has to enter login details each time?

Comment: This should do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961568/fill-fields-in-webview-automatically

Answer (score 0):

You should try with `WebView` which allows you to embed HTML page in your Android application.

Check this out: [`Building Web Apps in WebView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply! Actually I was thinking of doing that but as every user has got their own account details, like user id, name, etc, how to pull separate information for each user using WebView?