# How can I autofill a websites fields/forms in a WebView in Android Studio?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I want to autofill for example Facebook's login fields(email and password) or Google's search field. I have gone through many questions about autofill, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961568/fill-fields-in-webview-automatically).

This is my code at the moment, which opens up the website in the WebView, but doesn't fill out anything. And for the getElementById I inspected the facebook's email and password fields and their ID's were email and pass.

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            String user = "udb";
            String pwd = "abcdefg";
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('email').value = '" + user + "';document.getElementById('pass').value='" + pwd + "';");
            System.out.println("AUTOFILL");
        }
    });
```

and it gives me this error

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null", source:  (1)

I don't know much about javaScript though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I still can't get facebook to work, but I got google sign in to work and some other website register/sign ins. SO basically you need to inspect the website's elements(by using google chrome on desktop) and then get the element id;

this is the code to fill out a form/field:

```
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('last_name').value = '" + lName + "'; ;})()");
```

and this is the code to click a button:

```
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { var z = document.getElementById('signInButton').click(); })()");
```

Oh and I used my phone to do this, because with emulator it didn't do anything.

EDIT: I actually got facebook to kinda work by inspecting the mobile.facebook.com website, but there was no ID for email, only for password and login button and some other elements.

Comment: Do you know how to autofill the month in Google's [sign up form](https://accounts.google.com/signup). I can't get it to change with your method.

Answer (score 0):

Load the web page in the WebView:

In your activity or fragment, load the web page containing the login form in the WebView. Make sure to enable JavaScript if the page requires it:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://example.com/login");
```

To autofill the form with the username and password, you can inject JavaScript into the WebView. You'll need to know the **IDs or names of the input fields** in the web page's HTML source. For example, if the input fields have the IDs `username_input` and `password_input`, you can use the following code:

```
String username = "your_username";
String password = "your_password";

String js = "javascript:(function() { " +
        "document.getElementById('username_input').value = '" + username + "';" +
        "document.getElementById('password_input').value = '" + password + "';" +
        "})()";

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        view.loadUrl(js);
    }
});
```