# android webView autofill username and password not working

Tags: android, android-webview

I am passing username and password to the activity with webView. The problem is url loading is successful but i want to fill(autofill) username and password. I am a beginner, please help or give me any suitable github link.

```
    WebSettings webSettings = superWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    superWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {


            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('username').value = '"+userName+"';" +
                    "document.getElementById('password').value='"+password+"';");
        }
    });
    superWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Load the web page in the WebView: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76412796/12272687

Answer (score 0):

> call javascript as a function instead of this.

```
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
 view.loadUrl("javascript: (function() {document.getElementById('username').value= '"+userName+"';  document.getElementById('password').value='"+password+"';  }) ();" );
        }
```

> **Though the form must have "value" attribute.**

Answer (score 0):

**use this webview settings**
  `htmlWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            htmlWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data" + getPackageName() + "/cache");
            htmlWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
            htmlWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            htmlWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            CookieManager.getInstance().acceptCookie();`

replace htmlWebview With yourown webview

Comment: nothing has improved, fields are still getting empty.

Comment: it works for utofill form data only when the user selects input field except for passwords it also keeps login session only if the website is set to keep sessions for long time.