# C# Xamarin CrossPlatform App. Is there anyway to open default browser and automatically fill in username and password

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin, mobile, webrequest

I was able to open and autofill the information and click submit when I used selenium when running a console application. Is there anyway to do this same process for mobile devices? I was planning to use appinum, but considering that it uses a separate UI to automate the login, this doesn't seem viable. Any tips or hints would be useful. I have all the passwords and usernames stored in a database so retrieving them isn't the issue, and its for one site so implementing code specifically for one site also isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can run javascript on the page to manipulate the DOM using

`WebView.EvaluateJavascript()`

Such as:

```
  WebView mainBrowser = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.mainBrowser);
  mainBrowser.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
  mainBrowser.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
  mainBrowser.EvaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('foo').click();");
```

This would be for an embedded WebView. You would not be able to open another Application and automate input on it maliciously.

Answer (score 0):

My take for C# code in Microsoft Visual Studio...

Using...

```
using Android.Webkit;
```

The code...

```
public class LoginWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    static System.String username = "myusername";
    static System.String password = "mypassword";
    System.String js = "javascript:(function() { " +
            "document.getElementById('user_login').value = '" + username + "';" +
            "document.getElementById('user_pass').value = '" + password + "';" +
            "})()";

    [Obsolete]
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
    {
        view.LoadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, System.String url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        view.LoadUrl(js);
    }
}
public void LoadWebLogin(string url)
{
    web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
    web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    web_view.SetWebViewClient(new LoginWebViewClient());
    web_view.LoadUrl(url);
}
```

Usage...

```
LoadWebLogin("https://myWebsite.com/login.php");
```

From the following stackoverflow question...

[How can I autofill a websites fields/forms in a WebView in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087959/how-can-i-autofill-a-websites-fields-forms-in-a-webview-in-android-studio/76412796#76412796)