# Programmatically control WebView elements

Tags: android

If I have a WebView such as below

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Is there anyway to programmatically fill in the search text box? The text box has the name of `q`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can programmatically get the `WebView` to run JavaScript. You can use that to execute/query the DOM. Try something like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementByName('q').value = '" + queryHere + "';");
```

Just replace `queryHere` with a variable of your choice. You can similarly use JavaScript to then trigger form submits and other actions you might find useful.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961598/394933