# How to get auto suggestion in webview like chrome browser?

Tags: php, android, webview

In my `android app` I use `Webview` to login into a `php` website.
In chrome browser there is a feature called auto-suggestion in it(when the user enters the username for the first time and login. On second login the username will be displayed as a suggestion in it.).
I want that feature to be in my `Webview` app but I can't get it.

Something like this:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSofOt-pHJkA7TGmzqi8ijn390anlHxmiKMyMFkhjEQ8s4N2kiW

Comment: By "auto suggestion", do you mean "autofill"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961568/fill-fields-in-webview-automatically?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: No   *(I have given a new photo in the description. Check it out.)